# Can't retrieve <enclosure> element with WordPress default @fetch_rss();

Tags: php, rss

I'm trying to fetch and display items from another WordPress site's RSS feed.

I have everything working and have done this sort of thing before, but this time, the RSS feed I'm fetching has it's 'featured' images like so:

```
<enclosure url="https://cdn.canpl.ca/app/uploads/cpl/2022/01/10102550/DJC07504-e1641828489467-730x365.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

Now, I know exactly what I need to do with that once it's returned, not a problem at all... ...but then WordPress MagpieRSS decides to do its thing...

When I fetch the feed using:

```
$rss_feed       = @fetch_rss( $rss_src );
```

I don't actually get the `<enclosure>` tag returned.  So it looks as though WP is stripping that out.

The `var_dump($rss_feed)` shows:

```
object(MagpieRSS)#1266 (20) { ["parser"]=> NULL ["current_item"]=> array(0) { } ["items"]=> array(15) { [0]=> array(9) { ["points"]=> string(2) "10" ["title"]=> string(97) "WATCH: CPL Commissioner David Clanachan’s exclusive interview following Monday’s announcement" ["link"]=> string(112) "https://canpl.ca/link/watch-cpl-commissioner-david-clanachans-exclusive-interview-following-mondays-announcement" ["pubdate"]=> string(31) "Mon, 10 Jan 2022 17:33:08 +0000" ["guid"]=> string(112) "https://canpl.ca/link/watch-cpl-commissioner-david-clanachans-exclusive-interview-following-mondays-announcement" ["description"]=> string(20) " " ["content"]=> array(1) { ["encoded"]=> string(20) " " } ["summary"]=> string(20) " " ["atom_content"]=> string(20) " " } [1]=> array(9) { ["points"]=> string(2) "10" ["title"]=> string(124) "Commissioner David Clanachan Awarded Exclusive CPL Rights to Windsor/Essex County and to Step Down as First CPL Commissioner" ["link"]=> string(148) "https://canpl.ca/article/commissioner-david-clanachan-awarded-exclusive-cpl-rights-to-windsoressex-county-and-to-step-down-as-first-cpl-commissioner" ["pubdate"]=> string(31) "Mon, 10 Jan 2022 17:15:02 +0000" ["guid"]=> string(148) "https://canpl.ca/article/commissioner-david-clanachan-awarded-exclusive-cpl-rights-to-windsoressex-county-and-to-step-down-as-first-cpl-commissioner" ["description"]=> string(20) " " ["content"]=> array(1) { ["encoded"]=> string(9517) "
```

Genuinely not sure where else to turn.  I did find a MagpieRSS HotFix plugin, which actually just replaces the entire MagpieRSS functionality in WordPress, and was going to look at what was being done, but that plugin hasn't been updated in 13 years, so not sure how reliable that code is.

Anyone have any idea how I can get WordPress to stop stripping out the `<enclosure>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`fetch_feed()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/) instead. Example:

```php
$rss_feed = fetch_feed( 'https://canpl.ca/feed/rss2/' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss_feed ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $rss_feed->get_items( 0, 5 ) as $item ) {
        $enclosure = $item->get_enclosure();
        $enc_url = $enclosure ? $enclosure->get_link() : 'No enclosure found';
        echo '<li>' . $item->get_title() . "<br>Enclosure URL: $enc_url</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

However, to answer what's asked in the question:

WordPress does not strip the tag.. It's the [`MagpieRSS` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.3/src/wp-includes/rss.php#L34) that doesn't parse that tag.

So *if you want to use [`fetch_rss()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_rss/) to fetch the feed*, then you would have to edit the `wp-includes/rss.php` file... and modify the `feed_start_element()` method in the `MagpieRSS` class, in order to be able to have `enclosure` be parsed by that class. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236335) (that still worked in WordPress v5.8.3) except that you would add the code there to the `rss.php` file and not `rss_parse.inc` (which does not exist in WordPress).

But the `rss.php` file is actually deprecated, and if you enabled WordPress debugging, you'd see a notice saying, "*Deprecated:  rss.php is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use wp-includes/class-simplepie.php instead. in ...*".

So as I said earlier, you should use `fetch_feed()`. :)

Comment: Why am I not surprised that you were the one to answer. At this point I half expect you to wear a cape while answering questions on WPSE.  Thank you.  I ended up abandoning baked in methods all together and used PHP's native `simplexml` parsing, but navigating through the nested objects was tedious. I haven't deployed to live yet so I'll implement `fetch_feed()` later today.  Side Note:  I do have debugging enabled and didn't get any notice about the deprecation, or if I did it was tucked somewhere in the source I didn't look. :-/

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks again @Sally CJ.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) And I actually wanted to include [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19931084) in my answer, but `fetch_feed()` does the job pretty well and it also handles caching, hence it should be used unless maybe if you want to handle the caching on your own.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually just went and adjusted the caching for `fetch_feed()` - the source tends to release news items in bursts.  SimpleXML worked a treat but extracting what I needed from all those nested objects was very un-fun.